# Is there a book with only experiences related to elementary particles?

Tags: resource-recommendations, elementary-particles

Being in this unknown world, and feeling the known old notion of being into a game, about whose rules and field I am ignorant of; I thought of knowing the game field of this world, by receiving organized well ordered data--viz. without any leaps--instead of random data.

I thought to start from the origins of universe, Big Bang! But all these requires technical conceptual understanding (see Susan Carey's Origins of Concepts), so I can first learn math. But, math is a concept developed by humans, which has its own evolutionary back ground; for that, to proceed in a general way, I need to first understand humans. This, that; that, this...finally I arrived at the order of knowing only the experiences--those which are not "concepts" but direct experiences--of the elementary particles origins. As experiences are not bound much to the evolutionary stages as concepts are, I feel to have greater grip to start with it.

Am I then not willing to learn math? No. I have this order:
1. No-Concepts-Only-Experience (NCOE) Elementary Particle's Origin: Particle Physics, Quantum Mechanics, Cosmology, etc.
2. NCOE Compounds origin: Chemistry.
3. NCOE Origins of Species/Life on Earth: Molecular Biology, Neuroscience, Psychology.
4. Origins of Concepts: Math and theories.
5. Refreshing. Again going back to know the origins with more clarity.

So, now I have come in need of knowing the origins and evolution of elementary particles, without any concepts, as I come to that rigor only after completing first cycle of the above order.

All the above is to provide context. To make question narrow, I need a book which can help me have all the existing practical experiences on elementary particles. Is there any such book?

If there is anything to say on the order, it will also be really helpful (can be put in comments).

Answer (score 1):

It required the construction of the Large Hadron Collider, at a cost of billions of dollars, before anyone experienced a Higgs boson. And the experience consisted of having computers identify the decay products of a few collisions, out of trillions that were automatically recorded, as indicating that a Higgs boson had briefly existed there.

The idea of a book which starts with everyday experience, and describes the experiments required to demonstrate notions of force, charge, atom... all the way up to Higgs boson, definitely makes sense, but I do not believe it has been written. That information is scattered throughout textbooks. Perhaps it could be a Wikibooks project to put it all in one place.